# Filter a Dataframe where column date is between date1 and date2

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, row

I got following Dataframe (df1):

```
Date        A       B       C       D       E     

2000-10-04  6857    68964   6760    6823    6823    
2000-10-05  6819    6917    6819    6892    6892    
2000-10-06  6895    6921    6712    6776    6776
```

I want to create a new Datframe (df2) where only the rows in df1 are included where the date is between 2000-10-16 and 2001-03-01.

Answer (score 0):

One option is `between` that gives a logical `vector` as output which can be used in `filter` to keep those rows that have 'Date' in between those ranges

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    filter(between(ymd(Date), ymd('2000-10-16'), ymd('2001-03-01')))
```